# Accepting my own answer to my question

Tags: discussion, reputation, accepted-answer

I had asked this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/137593/6-7-linux-headers-make-mrproper-fails-in-lfs-7-5). No one answered it. I solved the problem on my system and answered the question.

Is it **OK** to accept one of my own answers?

I am asking this because there are no answers from other people. There **might not** be any answers from others.

<del>Or will it be cheating or unethical for accepting my own answer and gaining reputation points?</del>

**EDIT:** I accepted my answer for my question and it did not increase my reputation at all. So, the above point is moot.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer

Comment: @MichaelMrozek, got it. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's perfectly fine to accept your own answer to a question, regardless of whether it's the only one or one of many. The only thing that matters is that it answers your question, and you as the OP are marking an answer to denote that it solved your particular situation.

Comment: thank you. congratulations on being elected as `moderator`. all the best

Comment: Thank you very much. Same to you as well 8-)

Comment: I would also mention that if you're doing an ask-and-answer ("Answer your own question" box), that it is courtesy to wait a day or two before accepting to see if anyone else comes up with something better.

Comment: @Riking - if it's an ask-and-answer Q&A the SE site forces you to wait 2 days to accept your own answer anyway.

Comment: @slm whoops... Guess that's where i got the "advice" from then